# Wicket, GMap3, Overlay Click event, where did the user click? What is the coordinate (GLatLng)?

Tags: java, google-maps, wicket, wicketstuff

I have a [GCircle](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/master/jdk-1.6-parent/gmap3-parent/gmap3/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/gmap/api/GCircle.java) on a Wicket [GMap3](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/jdk-1.6-parent/gmap3-parent/gmap3). 
I want the user to be able to click on the map (add/remove markers) both in the circle, as well as out of the circle. Problem: the click event on the circle is not propagated to the map, as far as I understand, becaues the GCircle component adds the circle to the map as an overlay. I want to solve this by calling the Map's click event handler from the Circle event handler.

**Here comes the strange problem: I cannot extract the latitude/longitude that was below the cursor when the click event occurred on the circle.** This is how I create the circle and bind the event on it:

```
        GLatLng center = new GLatLng(47.46133874643204, 19.054965020623058);
        LOGGER.debug("Circle center:{}", center);

        // settings of the polygon's circle
        GCircle circle = new GCircle(center, shapeModelObject.getRadius(), "RED", 3, 1f, "", 0).
                setClickable(true).
                setEditable(true).
                setVisible(true).
                setDraggable(true);

        circle.addListener(GEvent.click, new GEventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                Request request = getRequest();
                IRequestParameters params = request.getRequestParameters();
                debugParameterValues(params);
                String latLng = params.getParameterValue("overlay.latLng").toString();

                latLng = latLng.substring(1, latLng.length() - 1);
                String[] d = latLng.split(",");
                Double lat = Double.valueOf(d[0].trim());
                Double lng = Double.valueOf(d[1].trim());
                GLatLng gLatLng = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
                LOGGER.debug("Click gLatLng:{}", gLatLng);
            }
        });
        map.addOverlay(circle);
```

This is the circle center in the logs:

```
Circle center:new google.maps.LatLng(47.46133874643204, 19.054965020623058, false)
```

This is what the Ajax request parameters look like /`debugParameterValues(params);`/:

```
Parameter name=5-1.IBehaviorListener.1-content-form-map-map, value=
Parameter name=id, value=444
Parameter name=argument0, value=[object Object]
Parameter name=overlay.latLng, value=(47.46133874643204, 19.054965020623058)
Parameter name=overlay.radius, value=500
Parameter name=overlay.overlayId, value=overlay831
Parameter name=overlay.event, value=click
Parameter name=center, value=(47.46096156028599, 19.052862168755382)
Parameter name=bounds, value=((47.45225641835252, 19.03792762896046), (47.46966526106453, 19.067796708550304))
Parameter name=zoom, value=15
Parameter name=currentMapType, value=ROADMAP
Parameter name=_, value=1394015901116
```

This is the result of `LOGGER.debug("Click gLatLng:{}", gLatLng);`, exactly the same as the circle center, no matter where the user clicks:

```
Click gLatLng:new google.maps.LatLng(47.46133874643204, 19.054965020623058, false)
```

Wicket version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicketstuff-gmap3</artifactId>
        <version>6.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I extract the latitude/longitude that was below the cursor when the click event occurred on the circle? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the z-index will solve the original problem, that is, the circle will not block clicking on the map.

```
circle.setZIndex(1);
```